# I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build CDO 4.10.0 from source code and caught the below error

`INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80: The target server failed to respond`

It looks like a bug according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552876 thread and seems it was fixed; however, I'm still getting this error each time I run `mvn install`.

The web page http://download.eclipse.org:80 itself is accessible from my Google Chrome, so it's not related to my Internet connection or something like that.

Does anybody know if it's possible to fix the error or is it a remote server related error and I can do nothing with it?

Comment: eclipse.org went full https a while ago. Perhaps your client version isn't paying attention to the redirect headers in the response? There *is* a response. Which Maven version are you using?

Comment: Hi @nitind, I use maven 3.8.8 with Java 1.8. Do I need to upgrade maven to the latest version?

Comment: @nitind I tried maven 3.9.4 but got the same errors. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Also I found ===INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://download.eclipse.org:443: The target server failed to respond=== message in mvn install output. So both 80 and 443 are not accessible.

Comment: It sounds like you have some kind of network connectivity issue to solve, even if Chrome is working correctly. Are you using a proxy? Does Maven build anything else without an issue?

Comment: No, I don't have a proxy. I tried two different networks and two differents PCs with no success. I can build other maven projects with no issues. Actually, my project depends on CDO 3.0.1 and I'm migrating to CDO 4.10.0. The project with CDO 3.0.1 can be built with no issues and maven can download all jars from maven repository. But the problem is they don't publish new CDO versions in maven repos anymore so I want to try building 4.10.0 CDO on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no way to build CDO 4.10.0 from scratch. Eclipse infrastructure was changed. See [Eike's comment](https://github.com/eclipse-cdo/cdo/discussions/7) here.